# How to add jar file reference in a batch file?

Tags: java

I have created a simple java class file say for displaying some text to user.
I have created the batch file for this program.
It is working fine when i placed it to same directory where my class file exists
but when i placed it somewhere else it is giving file not found exception or class not found exception and fails to display the text to user.
How this can be resolved?

I have tried also by creating the jar file of my class file but also it fails how can i add a jar file reference so that batch file invokes it?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you paste the batch file content to give us some more details? Probably the `CLASSPATH` is not set correctly.

Comment: You've created *what* batch file? With what in it? Not a real question.

Comment: Here is the contents, @echo off, javac Server, java Server how to set the classpath for the source file named Server

Comment: That's not even a valid batch file, let alone a valid javac command, let alone anything else. Have you considered reading the tools documentation for 'javac' and 'java'?

Answer (score 1):

What command are you running to launch your jar? On what environment are you running? This is the syntax for setting the classpath on Windows:

```
java -cp "./yourJar.jar;otherJars" your.class.with.Main
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the batch file, your main class, and how you are building your jar.

Comment: I have a source file say server and i am using following code to create a batch file                                              @echo off

javac Server.java

java Server also i have created a jar from eclipse by just selecting the export to jar option from menu.

Comment: As above, please edit your question posting code that exhibits the problem, the batch file, the exact error you get when you run it ad what else you have tried.